# Billing and Invoicing Software For Multiple Devices While Offline

Tags: offline, finance, invoicing

I am in need of invoicing software that can be used on Windows PC's and on and iPad. It needs to be able to do the following:

- Maintain a list of customers
- Maintain a list of items
- Create quotes & invoices

The most important feature is that when used on an iPad it must be able to be used while offline (i.e. no Internet access), and then synchronize the data with a desktop PC. It does not matter whether this is done later via the Internet, or even if it has be a matter of connecting the iPad to the desktop using a USB cable and clicking on a Sync button.

There are times when in the field, no Internet or cell phone service is available, and there is a need to create an invoice, or lookup item costs, or add a customer to the database.

The only software I've found so far that is capable of this is ServicePal. However, it's now $30 to $50 per month, and I cannot afford this.

Are there any cheaper options? Free would be ideal.

Some of the ones I've looked at so far:

- Xero - Can't be used offline
- NCH Express Invoice - Can use web-interface, but can't be used offline
- Quickbooks Online - Can't be used offline
- Quickbooks Desktop Version - Can't synchronize between multiple devices
- Sage 50 - iPad app only does time keeping
- Jobber - Can't be used offline
- Wave - Can't be used offline

Note: Software packages that require you to setup your own server are also acceptable.

Comment: In my juristication that would be tricky (=illegal) because invoice numbers need to be sequential and not be used more than once and in sync to their date. Do you need invoices in the field? Or how should the program guarantee that invoices are sequential in date AND number AND never be used twice without Internet access?

Comment: For my purposes, invoice numbers are not really a concern. They could simply be First Initial + Last Initial + 2 digit year + 2 digit month + 2 digit day